# Deserializing JSON array into C# object (TFL api)

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, serialization

I am trying to deserialize the London Underground API into C#. The API endpoint looks like this https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Mode/tube/Status and it is an array of JSON objects. I want to deserialize into a C# object but can't work out how to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TFL.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TubeApi : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTubeStatus()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.tfl.gov.uk");
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("/Line/Mode/tube/Status");
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var rawData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(stringResult);

                        return Ok(new
                        {
                            LineId = rawData.name
                        });

                }
                catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Error getting data");
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public class RootObject
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<LineStatus> lineStatuses { get; set; }

    }

    public class LineStatus
    {
        public string statusSeverityDescription { get; set; }

    }

}
```

However I get the following build error:

> List does not contain a definition for name.

I am new to JSON and have never had to deserialize from an array, usually from JSON `{"name":"value"}`.

Can anyone please help me to see where I have gone wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: `rawData`  is `List<RootObject>`. you can read values something like this `rawData[0].name`

Comment: Can you show the class `RootObject`?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou it is in the code snippet in the same file

Comment: `rawData` is a  `List<RootObject>`. You know that you deserialize it like that. And the error is right, List doesn't have a name property it's a list of object . Those object do have a property called `name`. If you already have handle a List of custom object then it will be the same here.

Comment: You should get an object of type `List<RootObject>` not `var rawData`.Then iterate the `List` of `RootObject` objects and get the name value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rawData` is a `List<RootObject>`. A `List<T>` doesn't have any properties named `name`.

Using `var` has his advantages and disadvantages, if you had used the right type I think you would have seen your mistake.

If you want to get the name of a line in your `List<RootObject>` you have to access one of its element. You can do it through multiple ways like :

```
rawData[0].name;
```

or

```
rawData.Find(x => x.name.Equals("MyLine"));
```

or

```
rawData.IndexOf("MyLine");
```

You can look at [List in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to get all names

```
var result = (from c in rawData select (new
            {
                LineId = c.name
            })).ToList();
return Ok(result);
```